# My computer is creating multiple shortcuts of folders present in the drive?

Tags: virus, shortcuts

Every folder in my computer has made its own shortcut . When i tried to delete some of the folders shortcut the shortcut files again started to get multiplied. Its not getting deleted?? What should i do?

Comment: You could start by telling us what OS and file manager you're using.

Comment: Shutdown the PC. Boot from a **clean installation** (e.g. a live CD with antivirus tools). Run a scan from that clean state. After that you have two choices: Try to fix (but never trust that PC again), or reinstall.

Comment: I am assuming that this indeed is a virus and that above scan will find it. I that is correct then please read this post: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit/157533#157533

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problen which u r facing now. You can remove the shortcut virus from your computer by downloading a software called 'Shortcut Virus Remover' . Its of great help in removing the shortcut files. 
U can also remove the virus using your cmd if you dont want to use any software. 
The article in the link below will surely help you in your problem. Its is a completr guide of how to remove shortcut virus.   http://techztricks.com/remove-shortcut-virus/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.